# boolean input to string yes for wantsToContinue in do while loop

Tags: java, string, boolean, do-while

I am trying to use a do while loop that will terminate if the user answers yes to "do you want to continue"  If I answer true in the console the loop functions properly, but, I would like to tell the user to input yes or no.  So, I searched for info on how to assign a string value to a `boolean` value of true but my code is not working. Can someone show me the proper syntax?

```
boolean wantsToContinue=String.equalsIgnoreCase("yes");

do{
    rollOne=diceOne.roll();
    rollTwo=diceTwo.roll();
    rollTotal=rollOne+rollTwo;
    //BoardSquare thePlayer.setLocation(square[]);

    Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Do you want to continue:");
    wantsToContinue = keyboard.nextBoolean();

} while (thePlayer.getBalance()>0 && wantsToContinue);
```

When I set it up this way I get non static method cannot be referenced from a static context. I need to avoid having a separate method or object for this logic.

Comment: Search for `non static method cannot be referenced from a static context.`

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve with the first line of code?  Doesn't something like that belong inside the loop, not outside?  And what should you write instead of "String" there?

Comment: i have. But everything i found involves creating an instance of an object, which, i need to avoid for the scope of the assignment.  Thx anyway.

Comment: @DavidWallace  I am getting a message that "the assigned value is never used", however, if i try to move the boolean variable assignment inside the do while loop, wantsToContinue, cannot be accessed.  Additionally, i tried to change String to Boolean, but, that does not work either.  I'm not sure if that's what you meant.

Comment: You don't want to use `nextBoolean()` on your scanner, because `nextBoolean()` always expects `true` or `false`.  You want to use a method that returns a `String` - either `next()` or `nextLine()` so that you can check what the `String` actually is.  So, what are you going to do with the `String` once you've got it, and where does `equalIgnoreCase` fit in?

Comment: @DavidWallace  I messed around with a few variations but i couldn't get it to work. I understand that equalIgnoreCase will insure user input is not case sensitive.  If i try to change the scanner input from nextBoolean() to nextLine() it gives me an error regarding incompatible types; even if i change boolean wantsToContinue to String wantsToContinue.  The only thing i can think of is to create a new variable to hold the string input, use method nextLine() In my mind i need to get a string input and convert it to a boolean. Or, assign a boolean value to a string so all other input is false

Comment: If `wantsToContinue` is declared as `String`, then `wantsToContinue = keyboard.nextLine();` does NOT throw an error regarding incompatible types.

Comment: @DavidWallace it does work.  I am not sure what i did the first time.  Thx so much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    String wantsToContinue="";

    do{

        rollOne=diceOne.roll();
        rollTwo=diceTwo.roll();
        rollTotal=rollOne+rollTwo;
        //BoardSquare thePlayer.setLocation(square[]);


        Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Do you want to continue:? yes | no");
        wantsToContinue = keyboard.next();

    } while (thePlayer.getBalance()>0 && wantsToContinue.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));
```

In each iteration prompt for yes or no. if you give **yes** the loop will continue(also based on your getBalance return >0). or it is terminate. **equalsIgnoreCase("yes")** it is check given option **yes** or **YES** or its combination. if equal it return true.

Comment: You should give an explanation,too.  Just giving code isn't really an answer.

Comment: this does not work.  If I answer no, the loop does not terminate.

Answer (score 0):

**equalsIgnoreCase** is not declared as static method in String class, but you are using it as **String.equalsIgnoreCase**. Hence the error **"non static method cannot be referenced from a static context"**